# Public Files in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm dipping my toes into ASP.NET 5 (vNext). To do that, I downloaded Visual Studio 2015 RC. I created a new ASP.NET Web Application. Then, in the next dialog I chose "Empty". From there I added a basic controller and a basic view.

I want to add bower and reference Zurb Foundation. However, I'm not sure how to do that. I've added a bower.json and .bowerrc file. Traditionally, I would install my bower packages in a directory called "libraries". I configured it like so:

**.bowerrc**

```
{
  "directory" : "/public/libraries"
}
```

Then, in my views, I'd have code that looked like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="~/public/libraries/foundation/foundation.min.css" />
```

I can see that when I run bower, I am in fact downloading the libraries and they are being placed in /public/libraries. However, when I deploy it, there seems to be an issue. It looks like the deployment is getting ran from wwwroot. However, I'm not sure what to do about

- Client-side packages loaded via bower
- My resources (i.e. images, css, javascript, fonts, etc.) that I need my app to use.

What do I need to do to access static files a) during development which seems to use the typical file structure and b) during deployment where the stuff seems to run from wwwroot?

Comment: Add static files middleware in Startup.cs

Comment: I have that already. However, its like it still cannot find the files. Does the public directory need to get copied to the wwwroot directory somehow?

Comment: Your grunt or gulp script should do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During development and production, you need to put stuff under the [webroot](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#webroot) if you have it defined. You can do this by gulp or grunt task. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/f0998dffbc5e6846515787eb931bd979753efd58/src/MusicStore.Spa/Gruntfile.js) for an example.

Assuming you have the following structure:

```
└───wwwroot
    ├───js
    │   └───foo.js
    │   └───bar.js
```

You will be able to reach out to them by:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" src="~/js/bar.js" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" src="~/js/foo.js" />
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Does that mean I need to have a grunt task that copies the files from `/public/packages*` to `/wwwroot/packages/*` If so, does Azure Websites run gulpfile.js during a deployment? Currently, I have the site working on my local machine. However, when I deploy as an Azure Website, its like it can't find the files.

Comment: How exactly are you publishing.  As part of the publishing the project will be built and that should include resolving all dependencies and running the task runner.  The client side packages should be already copied to the wwwroot as part of the publishing process.  To see a working example, create a new project using ASP.NET 5 template and publish it to the local file system.  You should see a /lib subfolder under wwwroot which contains all the client side dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be making reference in your views to the location of the bower dependencies, instead you should be referencing the relative path within wwwroot.

To see how it all fits I recommend creating a new project using the ASP.NET 5 Web Page template in VS 2015 RC.

In `package.json` your tool dependencies (resolved by npm) are listed.  Notice for the default project gulp is included here.  Gulp is the default task runner but you can use any task runner you like.  The bower dependencies by convention are defined in `bower.config`.

By convention the location for bower dependencies is `bower_components` off the 
project root.

If you look in `gulpfile.js` you will see that it copies the dependencies from bower_compontents to /lib off the project webroot (/wwwroot by default).

In the view _Layout.cshtml you will see the references to the libraries is ~/lib not /bower_components.

```
@inject IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - @AppSettings.Options.SiteTitle</title>

        <environment names="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel/css/bootstrap-touch-carousel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="hidden" asp-fallback-test-property="visibility" asp-fallback-test-value="hidden" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap-touch-carousel/0.8.0/css/bootstrap-touch-carousel.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel/css/bootstrap-touch-carousel.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="carousel-caption" asp-fallback-test-property="display" asp-fallback-test-value="none" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        </environment>
    </head>
```

So in summary:

1. Define client side dependencies in bower.config (or using some
   other package mananger)
2. Use gulp scripts to manage tasks (copying, minifying, etc).
3. Only make references in views to locations within webroot (using ~ relative paths).
4. When you build/publish all dependencies should be resolved prior to deploying
   to server.